# Central State Management without Redux or Mobx?

Tags: reactjs, redux, state, mobx, state-management

Recently I contemplated the idea of having central state management in my React apps without using Redux or Mobx, instead opting to create something similar to the application class in Android. In any event, I implemented something similar to this:

Create a store folder and a file called store.js in it whose contents are:

```
// State
let state = {
    users: {},
    value: 0
};

// Stores references to component functions
let triggers = [];

// Subscription Methods
export const subscribe = trigger => {
    triggers.push(trigger);
    trigger();
}

export const unsubscribe = trigger => {
    let pos = -1;
    for (let i in triggers) {
        if (triggers[i]===trigger) {
            pos = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (pos!==-1) {
        triggers.splice(pos, 1);
    }
}

// Trigger Methods
let triggerAll = () => {
    for (let trigger of triggers) {
        trigger();
    }
}

// State Interaction Methods
export const setUser = (name, description) => {
    state.users[name] = description;
    triggerAll();
}

export const removeUser = name => {
    if (name in state.users) {
        delete state.users[name];
    }
    triggerAll();
}

export const getAllUsers = () => {
    return state.users;
}

export const getUser = name => {
    if (!(name in state.users)) {
        return null;
    }
    return state.users[name];
}

export const getValue = () => {
    return state.value;
}

export const setValue = value => {
    state.value = value;
    triggerAll();
}
```

And connecting to this store in the following manner:

```
// External Modules
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Box, Text, Heading} from 'grommet';

// Store
import {subscribe, unsubscribe, getAllUsers} from '../../store/store';

class Users extends Component {
    state = {
        users: []
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        subscribe(this.trigger); // push the trigger when the component mounts
    }
    componentWillUnmount() {
        unsubscribe(this.trigger); // remove the trigger when the component is about to unmount
    }

    // function that gets triggered whenever state in store.js changes
    trigger = () => {
        let Users = getAllUsers();
        let users = [];
        for (let user in Users) {
            users.push({
                name: user,
                description: Users[user]
            });
        }
        this.setState({users});
    }

    render() {
        return <Box align="center">
            {this.state.users.map(user => {
                return <Box 
                    style={{cursor: "pointer"}}
                    width="500px" 
                    background={{color: "#EBE7F3"}} 
                    key={user.name} 
                    round
                    pad="medium"
                    margin="medium"
                    onClick={() => this.props.history.push("/users/" + user.name)}>
                    <Heading margin={{top: "xsmall", left: "xsmall", right: "xsmall", bottom: "xsmall"}}>{user.name}</Heading>
                    <Text>{user.description}</Text>
                </Box>
            })}
        </Box>;
    }
}

export default Users;
```

Note. I've tested this pattern on a website and it works. Check it out [here](https://phaes-buworks.netlify.com). And I apologize I am trying to keep the question concise for stackoverflow, I've provided a more detailed explanation of the pattern's implementation [here](https://github.com/AkhileshNS/phaes-buworks)

But anyway, my main question, what could be the possible reasons not to use this, since I assume if it was this simple, people wouldn't be using Redux or Mobx. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That's what Redux and MobX basically do, you are wrong in thinking that at their core concept they are much different. Their size and complexity came as a result of their effort to neutralize bugs and adapt to a vast variety of application cases. That's it. Although they might be approaching the task from different angles, but the central concept is just that. Maybe you should familiarize your self with what they actually do underneath.

Btw, you do not need to store redundant state in your component, if all you need is to trigger the update. You can just call [forceUpdate()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#forceupdate) directly:

```
// function that gets triggered whenever state in store.js changes
trigger = () => {
    this.forceUpdate();
}
```

That's similar to what Redux and MobX bindings for react do under the hood.